# Is there any profiler like visual studio profiler that works under Virtual Machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, profiling, profiler, virtual-machine

We are using ec2 lab to work on our product. The product currently I am working is written in LISP, Java, C/C++. It has a lot of components. My task is to profile it find performance bottleneck. I can load the C/C++ components in vs2008ts to compile it. As its a team system version, I can analyze it too. But the problem is visual studio profiler doesn't work on virtual environment.

So my question is, Is there any profiler that I can use in virtual envrironment? or is there any workaround for visual studio profiler??

Some necessary information

- Operating System: Windows Server 2003 R2
- Development Env: Visual Studio 2008 Team System
- Physical Memory: 7.5GB
- Application Type: MFC and Console
- SCM: Subversion

Comment: You should at least be aware of this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it helps, but the profiler in Visual Studio 2010 (Premium and Ultimate) does support profiling on virtual machines.

Also note that you can use Instrumentation Profiling with VS2008 on a virtual machine, although sample profiling is not supported.

Comment: Actually it depends on the guest OS too. You won't have any luck using Windows 8 or WIndows Server 2012. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2012/12/10/the-visual-studio-profiler-on-windows-8.aspx

Answer (score 1):

My company's [Profilers](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers) for C, C++ and Java are designed to operate in a variety of execution environments, including embedded environments.  They should run fine in a virtual machine, although you may have to configure them for what amounts to embedded environment execution.  That isn't hard.